# Is it true that async-await is functionally equivalent to a task continuation?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, task

I was looking at an explanation of `async`-`await` that said

```
async Task<int> IndexWordsFromAsync(string url)
{
    string content = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);
    int wordCount = AddContentToIndex(content);
    return wordCount;
}

int AddContentToIndex(string content)
{
   ... 
}
```

is equivalent to

```
Task<int> task = IndexWordsFromAsync(url);
var currentContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
task.ContinueWith(delegate
{
    if(currentContext == null)
        RestOfMethod();
    else
        currentContext.Post(delegate { RegstOfMethod(); }, null);
}, TaskScheduler.Current);
```

Can someone confirm to what extent this is true? Or can you link me to somewhere on the internet that describes `async`-`await` this way?

Answer (score 3):

> Can someone confirm to what extent this is true?

Do you have reason to doubt it? Without saying where you found this explanation it is difficult to critique it.

There are many, many details wrong there but the basic idea is sound.  Async-await is a syntactic sugar for construction of asynchronous workflows composed of tasks with continuations.

> Or can you link me to somewhere on the internet that describes async-await this way?

This isn't a site for recommending articles; you can do your own web searches.

If you want my articles on the subject, they are easily found:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/tag/async/

These are in most-to-least-recent order, so if you want to start from the beginning, go to the bottom of page two.

You might also consider reading the articles written by Jon Skeet, Stephen Cleary, Mads Torgersen, and Stephen Toub which are also easily found.